# How to limit the number of taps of a ball in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3

I am creating a game where at the first level I want the player to tap on the circles at a certain time. For example: How many taps can the player get at least 15 seconds. & when the player reach the maximum limit of taps at that certain time limit. Then, Congratulate the player.  Please, give me some help how to build this. 
here is some code of trying to limit the touches of the circles.

```
 let maxScore = 10
 var currentScore = 0

func playerScored(amount: Int) {

currentScore += amount

// I will be playing some sort of sound
// ...
}

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

if currentScore >= maxScore { // Player made it
    self.view!.presentScene(SKScene(fileNamed: "WinnerScene"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope u know about `UITapGestureRecognizer`have a look at Apple's documentation about tap `UITapGestureRecognizer` you will get some idea

Answer (score -1):

- **Objective - c** code is below :

UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doSingleTap)] autorelease];
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1; 
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doDoubleTap)] autorelease];
doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2; 
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];

[singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTap];

-->You can convert it into **swift**.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I put the code in my __touchesBegan but I don't see any changes. Can you tell me whats going on.

Comment: `You can convert to Swift` Don't be lazy, do it yourself. The question's tag is Swift, not Objective-C.